# How to append array of object to a jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to send some data over to another page. How would I append the array of objects: var tableData to the form? Im very new to jquery , so if there is another method i should be using to send all the data to another page, please advise. But all the other data is getting to the other page without any problem.

```
var tableData = $('tr[data-key]').map(function(){
    var row= $(this), key = row.data('key'),
    values= row.find(':input').map(function(){
         return this.value;
     }).get();

     return {
         key    : key,
         values : values
     };        
 }).get();;     
$('#download').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");

    var form = $("<form>", { action: "print", method: "POST", target: "_blank" });
    $("<input>", { name: "logo", value: $("#logo").html() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "header", value: $("#header").html() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "title", value: $("#title").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "table", value: $("#table").html() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "rules", value: $("#rules").html() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "payone", value: $("#payone").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "paytwo", value: $("#paytwo").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "paythree", value: $("#paythree").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "payfour", value: $("#payfour").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "payfive", value: $("#payfive").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "paysix", value: $("#paysix").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "payseven", value: $("#payseven").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "payeight", value: $("#payeight").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "bayone", value: $("#bayone").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "baytwo", value: $("#baytwo").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "baythree", value: $("#baythree").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "bayfour", value: $("#bayfour").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "bayfive", value: $("#bayfive").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "baysix", value: $("#baysix").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "bayseven", value: $("#bayseven").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "bayeight", value: $("#bayeight").val() }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", { name: "csrf", value: csrfToken }).appendTo(form);
    $("<input>", tableData.val() ).appendTo(form);

    form.submit();
});
```

The following below does not work

```
$("<input>", tableData.val() ).appendTo(form);
```

Comment: `val()` is used on form control elements not data arrays. If you want it in your form you need to stringify the data in array

Comment: Thanks for leading me down the right path. I used: $("<input>", {name: "tableData", value: JSON.stringify(tableData) }).appendTo(form);

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to get the desired results

```
$("<input>", {name: "tableData", value: JSON.stringify(tableData) }).appendTo(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to send a bunch of key -> values pairs to one input.

Perhaps you can loop through array, use the key as the name for an input then convert the values into a string (comma separated?) and put that as the value for the input.

This way you are making one input per key.